# Fitting a sum of exponentials using SVD

Tags: least-squares, svd

I'm running into some trouble attempting to fit a some experimental data using a (Linear Predictive) Single Value Decomposition (SVD) technique. My data looks like the sum of three or four exponentials, and it was suggested that SVD performs well given a large number of exponentials with some similar time constants. However, I'm having trouble understanding the technique.

I am following this guide, among others: https://ac.els-cdn.com/016974399580075K/1-s2.0-016974399580075K-main.pdf?_tid=7496bcf8-1045-11e8-962b-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1518475293_53ca92808cc7b673c7c38e8e9fdeea6d. My main confusion is regarding the Hankel matrix H, which contains the experimental data, and the matrix A, which contains the exponentials with time constants on it's diagonal. H contains hundreds of entries, while A contains 3 or 4 (because I am fitting to 3 or 4 exponentials). Yet, after some math, A = (product of some SVD and shifted H), eq (12), and "the exponents can be retrieved from the matrix A knowing the relation between the diagonal elements and exponents: a_ii = exp(b_i * t). This calculated matrix A has hundreds of diagonal entries, but I only want four exponentials. I don't see how this works as a fitting procedure. I also have varying time steps in the data, so I'm not sure that SVD even works without constant time steps.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Also, if someone has a better suggestion for fitting, I'd love to know. Currently the standard Matlab lsqcurvefit and fitnlm are producing unreliable / overparameterized fits, and I want a more robust method. Thank you.

Comment: Can't access the paper although I think you don't need any SVD to do that.

Comment: You can do it with linear least squares on some regularized fused matrix equations.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529505/can-i-find-a-power-of-a-closest-diffusional-operator-uniquely/2563561#2563561 <-- maybe this can give you inspiration if it makes any sense to anyone else than me.

Comment: The link makes some sense, looks like a similar approach of breaking the fit function f(x) into components. But I think it's less relevant because it's really trying to discretize or interpolate between two points, where I already have the points and I already have the form of f(x) (3 or 4 exponentials). I'll look into fused matrix equations though, thank you. 

In general, if you know of any other approaches to fitting that don't necessarily involve matrix decomposition, it would be useful. My naive approach has simply been using build in matlab functions, but there are probably options.

Comment: what i was thinking should make sense is the diagonal structure with 1 and -g, such a sequence of nested equations provides you exponential growth. The only thing you need to do is to simply replace I with 1 and G with g and then to summing a couple of those together and forcing them to become the sum you want them to be.